# Attempt to read property "name" on null in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-api, laravel-resource

I am working with laravel API and using model relationship and resource to get data, I don't know where is the problem that it gives such kind of error, I searched and tried the solutions, but the problem is still alive.

**This is my controller function:-**

```
 public function show(Question $question)
{
    return  new QuestionResource($question);
}
```

**This is the question model:-**

```
class Question extends Model
{
use HasFactory;
protected $guarded = [];
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug'; 
}

public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo (User::class, 'user_id');
}  
}
```

**This is the user model:-**

```
public function question(){
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Question::class);
}
```

**And this is the QuestionResource function:-**

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'title'=> $this->title,
        'slug'=>$this->slug,
        'body'=>$this->body,
        'created_at'=>$this->created_at->diffForHumans(),
        'updated_at'=>$this->updated_at->diffForHumans(),
        'user_name'=>$this->user->name,
    ];
}
```

**This is the question table:-**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('slug');
        $table->text('body');
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the solution is in the title — property "name" of null. You most likely do not have a user assigned to the Question model, so `$this->user` is `null`.

```php
'user_name' => $this->user->name
```

You might consider checking that a user exists first and setting a default value if it does not.

```php
'user_name' => $this->user ? $this->user->name : ''
```